How to understand the usage of 'turn' in the clause: no sensible writer delib­erately avoids turning a graceful phrase?
From [Joseph M. Williams. (1990). Style: Toward Clarity and Grace. p.preface]

At some level, of course, all writ­ers express feelings, all writers
imagine, no sensible writer delib­erately avoids turning a graceful
phrase, no matter how banal the subject.

What is the usage of 'writer delib­erately avoids turning a graceful phrase'?
Does 'turning a graceful phrase' mean 'constantly refining a sentence'?
Looking through the definition items in LONGMAN,I have found the proper definiton at best is 'to shape a wooden or metal object using a special tool'.

Check out Wiktionary’s entry for turn a phrase

First known use of "turn of phrase" is late 16th century and it is plausible, and some claim, that it indeed originates from the image of words being carefully shaped into an attractive form as a part is shaped on a lathe.

There is an idiom that the author is playing with  "turn a phrase", and the related "turn of phrase", meaning (to use) distinctive, or skilful language.  You can also use it to describe someone's manner of phrasing. So a "He has a graceful turn of phrase" means that he speaks or writes in a distinctively graceful manner.
I've seen a couple of suggestions of the origin of this expression, it could be from the notion that plain speech is "straight" but complex speech follows a curved path.  Or it may be from the analogy of how a woodturner will "turn a bowl" from a piece of wood by carving it on a lathe (see dictionaries)
So here "turning a graceful phrase" means "writing something distinctively graceful".

I'm not sure that I agree with the sentiment expressed in the original quotation. I am strongly reminded of Doctor Johnson's advice to writers: 'Read over your compositions, and wherever you meet with a passage which you think is particularly fine, strike it out, sir! Strike it out!' An editor once wrote: 'So many times when I’ve been reading work I’ve tripped on a well-turned phrase that somehow jars. When I point it out (which will invariably happen) the writer smiles ruefully, muttering ‘I know, I know… I should cut it, but I just love that line…’

One of my favourite writers is Ernest Hemingway, who wrote very plainly. My temptation is always to write too much. I keep it under control so as not to have to cut out crap and re-write. Guys who think they are geniuses because they have never learned how to say no to a typewriter are a common phenomenon. All you have to do is to get a phony style and you can write any amount of words.

I'd say that Hemmingway was a master of turning a phrase, precisely because he cut out the crap. He chose his words with great care.  The metaphor (if it is derived from wood turning) is cutting out a bowl from the wood, not building it up

I once read of a sculptor saying 'I take a block of stone and cut away everything that isn't the final result'.

@Michael Harvey In "I'm not sure that I agree with the sentiment expressed in the original quotation. " , do you mean "I'm not sure whether I agree with the sentiment expressed in the original quotation. "?

@Mr.Wang - I'm not sure that... means I doubt that, which is what I meant.

@Mr Wang - I’m not sure that; I’m not sure whether - The first phrase means “I doubt”, e.g. I’m not sure that we can make it in time; the second means “I wonder if; I don’t know if ” I’m not sure whether Shakespeare died in the 16th or the 17th century. - The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style

@Mr.Wang Consider 'I doubt that I agree' to be 'British polite reticence when stating an opinion'. Of course I know really that I don't agree.

@MichaelHarvey, the sculptor credited with that line is Michelangelo.
